# rename a directory or a file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I'm using Laravel 5.0 Facades Storage

> use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;

and I can use it like

```
Storage::..
```

In the Laravel 5.0 Docs,there's nothing like rename a file or folder from the storage.

Any help, ideas, clues, suggestions, recommendations on how to rename a file or folder using the Storage?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Laravel Docs

The move method may be used to **rename** or move an existing file to a new location:

```
Storage::move('hodor/file1.jpg', 'holdthedoor/file2.jpg');
```

this way, you can rename without moving

```
Storage::move('hodor/oldfile-name.jpg', 'hodor/newfile-name.jpg'); // keep the same folder to just rename
```

[Source](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/filesystem#storing-files)

Comment: i see, in php it could be like 'rename(oldname,newname,context)' so I'm looking for Laravel's way, anyway, thanks for the answer, how can I rename the file without moving it?

Comment: i will edit answer,, actualy its easy check edit (i just tested the answer and it works 100% )

Answer (score 2):

You can rename directories using

```
Storage::rename('oldFolder/', 'newFolder/');
```

Comment: Was looking for an answer to this question. Both using `rename` and `move` for renaming a folder doesn't work. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, I had almost the same issue but i solved it like this: `rename($path, $newPath)` using the built-in php function `rename()`,and guess what, everything worked like a charm!