# How can I solve File not found at path:... when rename file? (laravel)

Tags: image, laravel, laravel-5.3, filenames, file-rename

I see from here : [rename a directory or a file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37557903/rename-a-directory-or-a-file)

I try like this :

```
$destination_path = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'products'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product->id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product->photo;

$new_file_name = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'products'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product->id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_file_name;

// dd($destination_path, $new_file_name);

Storage::move($destination_path, $new_file_name);
```

There exist error :

> [League\Flysystem\FileNotFoundException]  File not found at path:
>   C:/xampp/htdocs/myshop/public/img/products/147/Zl756CDHovOZpEZz0jBYk73UCfO4zNmYDVWgLPpw.png

If I dd($destination_path, $new_file_name), the result :

> C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\public\img\products\147\Zl756CDHovOZpEZz0jBYk73UCfO4zNmYDVWgLPpw.png
>
> C:\xampp\htdocs\myshop\public\img\products\147\147-hazard-chelsea.png

I try check Zl756CDHovOZpEZz0jBYk73UCfO4zNmYDVWgLPpw.png in folder 147, the file exist

Why there exist error?

**Update** :

I had find the solution. I use php script like this :

`rename($destination_path, $new_file_name);`. It works

Comment: Whether there is no one to help?

Comment: please check dd(\Storage::exists($destination_path));

Comment: Storage use C:/xampp/htdocs/myshop/storage/app

Comment: @honarkhah, If I do `dd(\Storage::exists($destination_path));`, the result : `false`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Storage use **C:/xampp/htdocs/myshop/storage/app**
but your data store on public path

you can use **\Storage::exists($path)**;

```
$destination_path = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'products'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product->id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product->photo;

$new_file_name = public_path() . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'img' . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . 'products'. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $product->id . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $new_file_name;

// dd($destination_path, $new_file_name);
if(\Storage::exists($destination_path)){
    Storage::move($destination_path, $new_file_name);
}
```

Comment: I had try your code. It's no error. But it does not work to rename filename

Comment: I had find the solution. I use php script like this : `rename($destination_path , $new_file_name );`. It works

Comment: Storage use C:/xampp/htdocs/myshop/storage/app but your files on public path

Comment: if you want to use storage , firstly must save file on storage path , and then you can use storage , but when you save file on public path you must se pure php functions