# update file name of a file and updating data in database at the same time in laravel

Tags: laravel

I have a working upload file function. here's the code

```
public function store(Request $request)
{  
    $request->validate([
        'name' => 'required',
        'filename' => 'required|mimes:jpeg,png,jpg,gif,svg,doc,docx,xls,xlsx,pdf,txt|max:2048',
    ]);

    $fileName = auth::user()->id.'_'.$name.'.'.request()->filename->getClientOriginalExtension();

    request()->filename->storeAs('files', $fileName);

    File::create ([
        'name'      => $name,
        'filename'  => $fileName,
        'user_id'   => $request['user_id'],
        'extension' => request()->filename->getClientOriginalExtension(),
    ]);

    return redirect('dashboard/files')->with('flash_message', 'File added!');
}
```

now my problem is how am I going to update the filename of the file once I update the name in the database?

thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37557951/1095101

Comment: This suggestion works for me. Storage::move('hodor/oldfile-name.jpg', 'hodor/newfile-name.jpg');

Answer (score 1):

Well you may want to look at observers. That would be good practise.. Observers fires when CRUD operations done. So when you change a file name on database, you'll be there through observers.

first create an observer.

```
php artisan make:observer FileObserver --model=File
```

then register your observer on AppServiceProvider::boot.

```
public function boot()
{
    File::observe(FileObserver::class);
}
```

Open your FileObserver and edit "updated" method. Below method will run when a file record updated through File model.

```
public function updated(File $file)
{
    // get old file name
    $dirty = $file->getDirty();
    $oldFileName = $dirty["filename"] . "." . $file->extension;
    // get new file name
    $newFileName = $file->filename . "." . $file->extension;
    // replace old file name with new
    Storage::move('files/' . $oldFileName, 'files/' . $newFileName);
}
```

Comment: @Lito yes it does. But you have to rewrite that code everytime when you change the file name on database. If you use observers. you wont repeat same code over and over

Comment: ahh I see... copy @Teoman. I will take note of this. Thank you!