# how i can change copy url file name in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

i want to change this url https://www116.zippyshare.com/d/hljOkUHz/49620/Jungle.Cruise.2021.480p.WEB-DL.Hindi-Cam.English.MoviesVerse.Co.mkv filename to [https://www116.zippyshare.com/d/hljOkUHz/49620/Jungle.Cruise.2021.480p.WEB-DL.Hindi-Cam.English.{myWebsiteName}.mkv](https://www116.zippyshare.com/d/hljOkUHz/49620/Jungle.Cruise.2021.480p.WEB-DL.Hindi-Cam.English.%7BmyWebsiteName%7D.mkv)

Comment: Check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/37557951/407412

Comment: I have copied this URL(https://www116.zippyshare.com/d/hljOkUHz/49620/Jungle.Cruise.2021.480p.WEB-DL.Hindi-Cam.English.MoviesVerse.Co.mkv) from a third party website. I want to use it on my website.i want when somebody click on download button its start downloading with this name : Jungle.Cruise.2021.480p.WEB-DL.Hindi-Cam.English.MoviesVerse.Co.mkv i want to add here my website name : Jungle.Cruise.2021.480p.WEB-DL.Hindi-Cam.English.{mywebsitename.com}.mkv

Comment: The probably only way you could do that from your end, is by proxying the whole request through your server. And why do you want your site name in there to begin with - to make it easier for the copyright police to find _you_ as the party responsible for distributing links to copyrighted content? :-)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

If the structure of the incoming file name is always going to be the same (ie. you will always want to remove MoviesVerse.Co, and MoviesVerse.Co is always going to come right before the file format), you could use :

```
$filename = ""; // Whatever the incoming filename is
$bits = explode('.', $filename);
$filetype = array_pop($bits);
array_pop($bits);
array_pop($bits);
$bits[] = "YourWebsiteName";
$bits[] = $filetype;
$filename = implode('.', $bits);
```